# Css min-width no horizontal scroll bar is showing

Tags: html, scrollbar, css

i've built a site and I used min-width css

```
.body{
    overflow:auto;
    min-width:1600px;
}
```

but when It loads on smaller resolution it don't appear a horizontal scrollbar, what should I do to make horizontal scrollbar appear?

Comment: How wide is your content? You have to at least set a `div` tag inside `body` wider than 1600px

Comment: Could you show some HTML code? Is .body meant to be a class? Or should it be body?

Comment: Is there a clear answer to this question? The accepted one doesn't say anything at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to declare `overflow` if you want the scroll bar to be present as this is the default behaviour

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/kav7G/5/

You do need to set a `height` otherwise it will not work

Comment: thanks everyone but this seems to work for me! Thank you again everybody!

    html{
     min-width:1600px;
     height:500px;
     
     overflow-x:scroll;
    }