# table on content area div overflow,when browser is minimized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

see this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bumbumpaw/xm7ue6nf/1/) for codes.

when browser is minimized,table overflow outside div.
Noticed also that the `tableutils.js` I imported have this code ,

```
    fixHeaderOptions : {
     width : 600; //i commented out this so table width is not set but still table overflow. 
    }
```

My desire output is to have a scrollbar on the table area ONLY IF browser is minimized and do not overflow on **#content div** area(the div with gray background-color), when browser is maximized; i do not want any scroll bars to show on **#content div**.

Any help from you guys is much appreciated.

Comment: Questions about "why is this code not working as expected" should contain code in the question itself.

Answer (score 2):

adding overflow:auto; in your css file

```
   #mainContainer
   {
     min-width: 740px;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
     overflow: auto; // add this
   }
```

if you want to have a fixed scrollbar then change the "overflow:auto" to

```
overflow:scroll;
```

Comment: It's working .. you try minimize the size of the output space by dragging the border. The scrollbar is shown, you can also change the overflow:auto to overflow:scroll to see the different

Comment: Still part of table overflow outside content div(the gray area part)

Comment: You want only the gray part to be scrolled ?? when the browser is minimize?  and scroll bar is hidden when browser is maximize ?

Comment: yes,see this http://jsfiddle.net/bumbumpaw/p117n434/2/, this is correct but some of css is not applying here. And on the right panel of jsfiddle if i re-add the tableutils.js ,csss works but scroll shows on maximixed see this http://jsfiddle.net/bumbumpaw/p117n434/4/

Answer (score 1):

```
#outerDiv_searchMe{
width: 100%;
overflow: auto;
}
```

Use 100% width to make sure it auto-resize belongs to browser. Then, when browser minimized, it make the div's size smaller than table so, the scroll bar will display

Comment: It does have scrollbars, but it shows on both minimized and maximized browser. see this http://jsfiddle.net/m/ypr/

Comment: see my working [http://jsfiddle.net/nhannv152/p117n434/](http://jsfiddle.net/nhannv152/p117n434/)

Comment: you only add ths .demoContentDIV {
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
}?

Comment: I only added `width:100%; overflow:auto;` into the div which wrapped the table

Comment: thanks,unmark this answer for now,but why do some of my css is not working?

Comment: Your jsfiddle is working directly with your required, what css didn't work?

Comment: on the css area, starting from this comment sir /*starting for here*/ @Nhan Nguyen

Comment: ok I found your problem, on the left panel of jsfiddle, click External Resources, remove `tableutils.js` and then re-add it to make sure it must be load after `jquery-1.9.1.min.js` is loaded

Comment: as I said, you must re-apply the `css` above to the `div` which wrapped the `table` because the html was changed after you apply `tableutils.js`

Comment: that what i do, see this sir http://jsfiddle.net/bumbumpaw/p117n434/4/ and for full page sir http://jsfiddle.net/m/uxm/

Comment: you must add `overflow: auto; width: 100%;` to the selector `#outerDiv_searchMe`, it's the wrapper of the table

Answer (score 1):

Here's my working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chajadan/xm7ue6nf/16/

To make the page give a horizontal scrollbar when minimized, set a height on the main content div. overflow:auto is not necessary to get scrollbars to show up upon need.

```
#mainContainer {
    min-width: 740px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
```

By googling "min-width overflow:auto but no scrollbars" I got this part of my answer from here: [Css min-width no horizontal scroll bar is showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18855961/css-min-width-no-horizontal-scroll-bar-is-showing)

I made the following additional changes as well.

I also removed the searchMe table width so the table wasn't arbitrarily wide, which could cause scrollbars even when the window is more than big enough to fit the tabular data.

```
<table id="searchMe" width="980px">
```

There were two break elements that were also making the tabular data wider than useful, which I removed.

```
</div>
<br>
<br>
```

The table header still doesn't line up with the body cells, but wasn't the main thing questioned here.

Comment: hello sir, can you check my css code, some of them are not working. http://jsfiddle.net/chajadan/xm7ue6nf/16/ strating from the `table.fixedWidth`

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for (and you sent me back my same fiddle link), but maybe this fiddle helps: http://jsfiddle.net/xm7ue6nf/18/

I took out the thead and tbody parts and then all the columns line up right. I'm thinking the javascript is mangling that table somehow (didn't look into it), because when I used chrome dev tools to look at the header verse the body, they seems to suddenly be in different tables when I leave the thead and tbody part, but perhaps you need those if that javascript is trying to distinguish records from labels.